# Upload Application to app store with iPad support and later on iPhone Support

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have an application which is practically done and ready to be issued as an iPad version, but the problem is that later on i need to have an iPhone version of it to be submitted using the same bundle and the same app id.
 I know that i need to create a different storyboard or use the auto-layout, so coding and developing wise i already have it figured out, but for now i need to submit the iPad version of it and after on submit an update containing the iPhone version. Is there any pointer i should keep in mind or any special details to watch out from? Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just upload your first version with configuration stated below screenshot [image]

After when u want to upload with both then do config stated in belowed screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**It's simply possible to update your iPad app with your new universal app**. nothing any importent changes for configuration at iTune but you must know well how to develop the Universal app